# Dependent variable distribution

Tags: multiple-regression

Can someone please help me address the following two doubts.

1. First question: I have often heard from practitioners that you should plot the dependent variable and see the way it is distributed. That should hint you towards what kind of regression you should use. If it is normal, then general linear model, if it is right skewed and discreet data then Poisson etc. However, I have always found it confusing. A regression model assumes how the dependent variable is distributed *conditional* on X. Specifically, any regression model assumes how a "single" data point (*Yi*) is distributed conditional on X (Gaussian, Poisson, etc. etc.). This is different from the distribution of Y which is the entire dataset. Am I missing something here? So suppose I plot the histogram of the dependent variable in my dataset and see that it is normally distributed, that is, I plot all Yi (i = 1 to N) in my dataset and see a Gaussian distribution. Does it necessarily mean that each Yi is also Gaussian? I think it is the distribution of a single Yi that should decide the regression model, and not the distribution of my dataset *Yi* (i = 1 to N). However, we do not see the distribution of *Yi*, we see only one realization from that distribution and that is the data we have. So then how do we really know how Yi is distributed?
2. Second question: suppose I want to run a multiple linear regression with two independent variables X1 and X2. The scatter plot of (X1,Y) resembles Gaussian and that of (X2,Y) resembles a Poisson distribution. What does this tell me?

Thanks a lot! I am new here so apologies if I did not follow any rules inadvertently.

Comment: In what sense does a scatterplot, which is two dimensional, "resemble" any kind of *univariate* distribution?

Comment: @whuber, in the sense that the word "resemble" conveys -- to look like or be similar. I understand your implicit point about how a univariate distribution could have anything to do with a bivariate scatterplot, and that is exactly my point. Just because they "look similar" does it mean anything (at all) or is it just a coincidence?

Comment: You should include the graphs. You also might study the terms "marginal" and "conditional" distributions. The entire Y data set *estimates* the marginal Y distribution. The simplest way to think about *estimating* a conditional distribution of Y for a particular X is to use the set of observed Y values corresponding to that particular X. As you suggest, there may only be one Y value for some such X, and this case you need to be more inventive, using near neighbors and smoothing methods

Comment: I think it's more common to (initially) choose you model based on the *nature* of your dependent variable than based on it's distribution. If it's continuous -> linear, if binary -> logistic, if count -> poisson, if ordinal -> ordinal logistic.

Answer (score 2):

*Question 1*. To "plot the dependent variable and see the way it is distributed" (its marginal distribution, as pointed out by @BigBendRegion) isn't useful, for the reasons that you state. The assumptions behind statistical tests have to do with distributions of outcomes conditional on predictors. Judging from questions on this site, that nevertheless still seems to be taught (erroneously) as an approach in many courses on statistics.

*Question 2*. That really isn't much of an advance over what's discussed in Question 1. Each individual plot is just marginalizing over the values of the omitted predictor variable. As you note, what you really care about is outcomes conditional on both the predictor values. What's to be gained by those plots?

The usual best practice is summarized in a comment by @Sointu: start by choosing the type of model based on the *nature* of the outcome variable, not on a marginal distribution. To extend that list beyond continuous, binary, count, and ordinal: multinomial if there are more than 2 unordered categorical outcomes; possibly log-transformed continuous if outcomes are necessarily positive with errors proportional to actual values instead of independent.

Comment: What if we dont know the true nature of the outcome variable and observed data is all we have.

Comment: @SundownBrownbear by "nature" I just mean which of the following types of data: continuous over all real numbers, continuous restricted to positive or non-negative real numbers, count, binary, unordered multi-category (multinomial), ordered multi-category (ordinal, which can be [extended to large numbers of ordered outcomes](https://www.fharrell.com/post/rpo/)), circular data (like angles), truncated or censored data (as in survival times). Each of those has ways recommended to begin analysis, which might need to be adapted as you go into more detail.

Comment: Thanks EdM, that makes sense.